# How to inherit and initialize a parent class method

Tags: python, class, inheritance, methods, statsmodels

I want to use the **FTestAnovaPower.solve_power** function from the parent class and get some values and them do some additional evaluation in the **PwrAnalysis** class. but im having trouble passing the arguments to the parent class. i'm trying to inherit a function with the below code.

```
import statsmodels.stats.power
class PwrAnalysis(statsmodels.stats.power.FTestAnovaPower):

def __init__(self,effect_size, nobs, alpha, power, k_groups):
    statsmodels.stats.power.FTestAnovaPower.__init__(self,effect_size, nobs, alpha, power, k_groups)
```

when i try to run
`c=PwrAnalysis.solve_power(effect_size=0.33, nobs=None, alpha=0.04, power=0.8, k_groups=3)`
i get "solve_power() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"

for reference the below code runs fine:

```
x = statsmodels.stats.power.FTestAnovaPower()
g = x.solve_power(effect_size=0.33, nobs=None, alpha=0.04, power=0.8, k_groups=3)
```

i am passing the self argument, i dont understand why its asking me to pass self again

Comment: Why in one snippet do you do: `c=PwrAnalysis.solve_power(...`, but in the next you have `g = x.solve_power(...`? Why don't you use `x.solve_power(...` in the first also?

Comment: Also, if your reference code is correct, you are saying that `FTestAnovaPower()` needs no parameters. If so, then your `class PwrAnalysis` needs no `__init__()` method (or needs to call `FTestAnovaPower.__init__()`)

Comment: You haven't created an *instance* of `PwrAnalysis` first. The working code *does* create an instance of `FTestAnovaPower` and uses *that*, not FTestAnovaPower` itself, to invoke the method.

Comment: Why do you want to pass `effect_size, nobs, alpha, power, k_groups` to `__init__`? In the design of the Power classes, those are arguments to the methods and not fixed for an instance of the power class.

Comment: `statsmodels.stats.power.FTestAnovaPower.__init__` should be replace with a `super` call, however, the parent class will just ignore those `kwargs` in `__init__`

Comment: thanks to everyone who replied. It turns out i was referencing class that could not me accessed.